# Search for string in multiple text files of size 150 MB each C#

Tags: c#, copy

I have multiple .txt files of **150MB** size each. Using C# I need to retrieve all the lines containing the string pattern from each file and then write those lines to a newly created file.

I already looked into similar questions but none of their suggested answers could give me the fastest way of fetching results. I tried regular expressions, linq query, contains method, searching with byte arrays but all of them are taking more than 30 minutes to read and compare the file content.

My test files doesn't have any specific format, it's like raw data which we can't split based on a demiliter and filter based on DataViews.. Below is sample format of each line in that file.

**Sample.txt**

```
LTYY;;0,0,;123456789;;;;;;;20121002 02:00;;
ptgh;;0,0,;123456789;;;;;;;20121002 02:00;;
HYTF;;0,0,;846234863;;;;;;;20121002 02:00;;
Multiple records......
```

**My Code**

```
using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(newFile))
            {
                using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sourceFilePath))
                {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
                {
                   if (sr.ReadLine().Contains(stringToSearch))
                     SW.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine().ToString());
                 }
}
}
```

I want a sample code which would take less than a minute to search for *123456789* from the Sample.txt. Let me know if my requirement is not clear. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I found the root cause as having the files residing in a remote server is what consuming more time for reading them because when I copied the files into my local machine, all comparison methods completed very quickly so this isn't issue with the way we read or compare content, they more or less took the same time.

*But now how do I address this issue, I can't copy all those files to my machine for comparison and get OutOfMemory exceptions*

Comment: Use a Database, for crying out loud.

Comment: No delimiters?  The samples show delimiters, does this mean that you are expecting to match both:;123456789; and ;abc1234567890abc;?

Comment: @Blah_Blah yes indeed! Even if not, Will it not take good amount of time to read all the file content to split data into string or byte arrays and then compare each because I think reading all the file content is what's taking more time?

Answer (score 3):

Fastest method to search is using the [Boyer–Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) as this method not require to read all bytes from the files, but require random access to bytes **or** you can try using the [Rabin Karp Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm)

or you can try doing something like the following code, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2097538/712603):

```
  public static int FindInFile(string fileName, string value)
  {   // returns complement of number of characters in file if not found
    // else returns index where value found
  int index = 0;
   using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName))
   {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return 0;
    StringSearch valueSearch = new StringSearch(value);
    int readChar;
    while ((readChar = reader.Read()) >= 0)
    {
        ++index;
        if (valueSearch.Found(readChar))
            return index - value.Length;
    }
}
return ~index;
}
 public class StringSearch
 {   // Call Found one character at a time until string found
private readonly string value;
private readonly List<int> indexList = new List<int>();
public StringSearch(string value)
{
    this.value = value;
}
public bool Found(int nextChar)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < indexList.Count; )
    {
        int valueIndex = indexList[index];
        if (value[valueIndex] == nextChar)
        {
            ++valueIndex;
            if (valueIndex == value.Length)
            {
                indexList[index] = indexList[indexList.Count - 1];
                indexList.RemoveAt(indexList.Count - 1);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                indexList[index] = valueIndex;
                ++index;
            }
        }
        else
        {   // next char does not match
            indexList[index] = indexList[indexList.Count - 1];
            indexList.RemoveAt(indexList.Count - 1);
        }
    }
    if (value[0] == nextChar)
    {
        if (value.Length == 1)
            return true;
        indexList.Add(1);
    }
    return false;
}
public void Reset()
{
    indexList.Clear();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how long this will take to run, but here are some improvements:

```
using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(newFile))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sourceFilePath))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (line.Contains(stringToSearch))
                SW.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need `Peek`, `EndOfStream` will give you what you want. You were calling `ReadLine` twice (probably not what you had intended). And there's no need to call `ToString()` on a `string`.

Comment: You can make that REALLY shorter with: `            File.AppendAllLines("b.txt", File.ReadLines("a.txt").Where(x => x.Contains("123456789")));
`

Comment: @YoryeNathan you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Jon, Thanks for the reply and I made your proposed changes but there isn't any improvment in the time it takes.

Answer (score 1):

150MB is 150MB. If you have one thread going through the entire 150MB, line by line (a "line" being terminated by a newline character/group or by an EOF), your process must read in and spin through all 150MB of the data (not all at once, and it doesn't have to hold all of it at the same time). A linear search through 157,286,400 characters is, very simply, going to take time, and you say you have many such files.

First thing; you're reading the line out of the stream twice. This will, in most cases, actually cause you to read two lines whenever there's a match; what's written to the new file will be the line AFTER the one containing the search string. This is probably not what you want (then again, it may be). If you want to write the line actually containing the search string, read it into a variable before performing the Contains check.

Second, String.Contains() will, by necessity, perform a linear search. In your case, the behavior will actually approach N^2, because when searching for a string within a string, the first character must be found, and where it is, each character is then matched one by one to subsequent characters until all characters in the search string have matched or a non-matching character is found; when a non-match occurs, the algorithm must go back to the character after the initial match to avoid skipping a possible match, meaning it can test the same character many times when checking for a long string against a longer one with many partial matches. This strategy is therefore technically a "brute force" solution. Unfortunately, when you don't know where to look (such as in unsorted data files), there is no more efficient solution.

The only possible speedup I could suggest, other than being able to sort the files' data and then perform an indexed search, is to multithread the solution; if you're only running this method on one thread that looks through every file, not only is only one thread doing the job, but that thread is constantly waiting for the hard drive to serve up the data it needs. Having 5 or 10 threads each working through one file at a time will not only leverage the true power of modern multi-core CPUs more efficiently, but while one thread is waiting on the hard drive, another thread whose data has been loaded can execute, further increasing the efficiency of this approach. Remember, the further away the data is from the CPU, the longer it takes for the CPU to get it, and when your CPU can do between 2 and 4 billion things per second, having to wait even a few milliseconds for the hard drive means you're losing out on millions of potential instructions per second.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Keith, I'll try creating multiple threads but besides multi-threading, Can you tell me how can I sort a text file that has lines with no common pattern.

Comment: Honestly, you can't. That's the problem; systems that are designed to store large amounts of data, like RDBMSes, do so in an ordered fashion (the order may not make much sense to you or me, but the computer can quickly drill into it). For dealing with flat files, you're pretty much doing exactly what you should be; reading a single line at a time. The problem is that this strategy requires you to read every single line in every single file, one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

As I said already, you should have a database, but whatever.

The fastest, shortest and nicest way to do it (even one-lined) is this:

```
File.AppendAllLines("b.txt", File.ReadLines("a.txt")
                                 .Where(x => x.Contains("123456789")));
```

But fast? 150MB is 150MB. It's gonna take a while.
You can replace the `Contains` method with your own, for faster comparison, but that's a whole different question.

Other possible solution...

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var x in File.ReadLines("a.txt").Where(x => x.Contains("123456789")))
{
    sb.AppendLine(x);
}

File.WriteAllText("b.txt", sb.ToString()); // That is one heavy operation there...
```

Testing it with a file size 150MB, and it found all results within 3 seconds. The thing that takes time is writing the results into the 2nd file (in case there are many results).

Comment: Yorye, I don't see AppendAllLines method in File class. I have .NET framework 3.5 and should have told that in my question. Can you suggest alternative solution.

Comment: @user841311 - You should update your question to reflect that fact.

Comment: Done. Results are satisfying.

Comment: strange! I don't know why but for me it's still running since 10-15 minutes using your solution. Is it because the files reside on a remote machine that it takes longer time to read the content.

Comment: @user841311 - Your problem is slow IO. With that issue, we can come with million solutions and none of them is going to be okay for you...

Comment: @user841311 DUH.. Nothing to do about that. Have the files sent over and the whole procedure will be faster than ever.

Comment: yes IO is what consuming more time as I removed the comparison part and had it just read line by line like @Ωmega suggested, its still been running for a while..I'll try copying the files to local machine and give a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not giving you sample code, but have you tried sorting the content of your files?

trying to search for a string from 150MB worth of files is going to take some time any way you slice it, and if regex takes too long for you, than I'd suggest maybe sorting the content of your files, so that you know roughly where `"123456789"` will occur before you actually search, that way you won't have to search the unimportant parts.

Comment: @JonB I missed the part where they're 150 each, i thought it was 150mb spread across multiple files

Answer (score 0):

Do not read and write at same time. Search first, save list of matching lines and write it to file at the end.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
...
List<string> list = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("input.txt")) {
  string line;
  while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
    if (line.Contains(stringToSearch)) {
      list.Add(line); // Add to list.
    }
  }
}
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("output.txt")) {
  foreach (string line in list) {
    writer.WriteLine(line);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried seperating them but no improvment in time elapsed for the search operation. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @user841311 - So do just blank reading with no search to find out if IO operations is not what takes so long. `while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) { ; }`

Answer (score 0):

You're going to experience performance problems in your approaches of blocking input from these files while doing string comparisons.

But Windows has a pretty high performance GREP-like tool for doing string searches of text files called [FINDSTR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) that might be fast enough. You could simply call it as a shell command or redirect the results of the command to your output file.

Either preprocessing (sort) or loading your large files into a database will be faster, but I'm assuming that you already have existing files you need to search.

Comment: I think this is the right direction, an OS tool can probably do this quicker.  In linux it would be a simple grep command piping output to a txt file and would likely complete much quicker.  The other option would be to copy the entire file into memory and then do your string comparisons there, flushing upon completion.